# filtering a df values within quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am generating a df from command line result with code like below :-

```
df_output_lines = [s.split() for s in os.popen("my command linecode").read().splitlines()]
df_output_lines  = list(filter(None, df_output_lines))
```

and tehn converting it into a dataframe :-

```
df=pd.DataFrame(df_output_lines)
df
```

the data is in the below format :-

```
abc = pd.DataFrame([['time:"08:59:38.000"', 'instance:"(null)"','id:"3214039276626790405"'],['time:"08:59:38.000"', 'instance:"(Ops-MacBook-Pro.local)"','id:"3214039276626790405"'],['time:"08:59:38.000"', 'instance:"(Ops-MacBook-Pro.local)"','id:"3214039276626790405"']])
abc
```

[image]

I want to filter it in a way so that value `before :` will be the column name and the values within the `quotes " "` be the value and same goes for all columns.  The output should be like :-
[image]

As of now i am doing it the hard way :-

```
abc.rename(columns={0:'time',1:'instance',2:'id'},inplace=True)
```

and then

```
abc['time'] = abc['time'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
abc['time'] = abc['time'].map(lambda x: str(x)[6:])

abc['instance'] = abc['instance'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
abc['instance'] = abc['instance'].map(lambda x: str(x)[10:])

abc['id'] = abc.id.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
```

Any suggestion for lambda expression or any one liner to do this.

My out put for the raw log is like below :-

```
    time:"11:22:20.000" instance:"(null)" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"0.000631" level:"info" operation:"Init" message:"Initialize (version 4.9.0002.30618) ... "

    time:"11:22:21.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"0.067122" level:"info" operation:"Connect" message:"Connecting to https://hrpd.www.vivox.com/api2/"

    time:"11:22:23.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl-.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"2.685700" level:"info" operation:"Connect" message:"Connected to https://hrpd.www.vivox.com/api2/"

    time:"11:22:23.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl-.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"2.814268" level:"info" operation:"Login" message:"Logged in .tester_food."

    time:"11:22:23.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl-.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"2.912255" level:"error" operation:"Call" message:".tester_food. failed to join sip:confctl-2@hrpd.vivox.com error:Access token has invalid signature(403)"

 time:"12:30:41.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"10316899144153251411" channel:"sip:confctl-2@hrpd.vivox.com" type:"media" sampleperiod:"0.000000" incomingpktsreceived:"0" incomingpktsexpected:"0" incomingpktsloss:"0" incomingpktssoutoftime:"0" incomingpktsdiscarded:"0" outgoingpktssent:"0" predictedmos:"3" latencypktssent:"0" latencycount:"0" latencysum:"0.000000" latencymin:"0.000000" latencymax:"0.000000" callid:"2477580077" r_factor:"0.000000"
```

Comment: This looks like you didn't call the correct `DataFrame` constructor. Did you start with a dictionary or json?

Comment: this log is being generated on command line and i am capturing it in a data farme with code

Comment: I'm thinking the same as @ALollz here... what does a few lines of your raw log file look like? Loading it in a different way from the start is likely to be much easier and reliable...

Comment: @JonClements  i have edited my question .

Comment: @ALollz i have edited my question.

Comment: check your file. it seems the dict file is not properly structured

Comment: @MEdwin its not a dictionary i am parsing result on command line.

Comment: @ak333, i have added a regex solution which matched the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Feed list of dictionaries to `pd.DataFrame`

The `pd.DataFrame` constructor accepts a list of dictionaries directly. You can use `str.rstrip` and `str.split` within a list comprehension:

```
res = pd.DataFrame([dict(i.rstrip('"').split(':"') for i in row) for row in abc.values])

print(res)

                    id                 instance          time
0  3214039276626790405                   (null)  08:59:38.000
1  3214039276626790405  (Ops-MacBook-Pro.local)  08:59:38.000
2  3214039276626790405  (Ops-MacBook-Pro.local)  08:59:38.000
```

It's unclear what logic you use to determine only `'null'` strings are surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: its giving me an error "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Comment: @ak333, I'm using *your* definition of `abc` and it works fine for me.

Comment: i am using    abc = pd.DataFrame([['08:59:38.000', '(null)','3214039276626790405'],['08:59:38.000', 'Ops-MacBook-Pro.local','3214039276626790405'],['08:59:38.000', 'Ops-MacBook-Pro.local','3214039276626790405']])
res = pd.DataFrame([dict(i.rstrip('"').split(':"') for i in row) for row in abc.values])

Comment: @ak333, That's the problem, use `abc` as you defined in your question.

Comment: I apologize..i got it. @jpp

Comment: Isn't the original data read breaking data anyway here? @ak333 if one of your input lines is `time:"11:22:23.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl-.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"2.814268" level:"info" operation:"Login" message:"Logged in .tester_food."` - then you don't want to be splitting message after the first word do you ?

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer is already produced, However would like to add a regex base approach to achieve the same:

```
>>> abc
                  time                            instance                        id
0  time:"08:59:38.000"                   instance:"(null)"  id:"3214039276626790405"
1  time:"08:59:38.000"  instance:"(Ops-MacBook-Pro.local)"  id:"3214039276626790405"
2  time:"08:59:38.000"  instance:"(Ops-MacBook-Pro.local)"  id:"3214039276626790405"
```

Just applying `regex=True` within DataFrame.

```
>>> abc.replace('instance:|id:|time:|\"|[()]', '',regex=True)
           time               instance                   id
0  08:59:38.000                   null  3214039276626790405
1  08:59:38.000  Ops-MacBook-Pro.local  3214039276626790405
2  08:59:38.000  Ops-MacBook-Pro.local  3214039276626790405

OR   

# abc.replace('(instance:|id:|time:)|\"|[()]', '',regex=True)
```

**regex explanation:**

> - 1st Alternative 'instance: 'instance: matches the characters 'instance: literally (case sensitive)
> - 2nd Alternative id: id: matches the characters id: literally (case sensitive)
> - 3rd Alternative time: time: matches the character time: literally (case sensitive)
> - 4th Alternative \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
> - 5th Alternative [()]' Match a single character present in the list below [()]
>     () matches a single character in the list () (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Given your example input of:

```
time:"11:22:20.000" instance:"(null)" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"0.000631" level:"info" operation:"Init" message:"Initialize (version 4.9.0002.30618) ... "

time:"11:22:21.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"0.067122" level:"info" operation:"Connect" message:"Connecting to https://hrpd.www.vivox.com/api2/"

time:"11:22:23.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl-.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"2.685700" level:"info" operation:"Connect" message:"Connected to https://hrpd.www.vivox.com/api2/"

time:"11:22:23.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl-.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"2.814268" level:"info" operation:"Login" message:"Logged in .tester_food."

time:"11:22:23.000" instance:"Ops-MacBook-Pro.local" id:"723927731576482920" channel:"sip:confctl-.com" type:"control" elapsedtime:"2.912255" level:"error" operation:"Call" message:".tester_food. failed to join sip:confctl-2@hrpd.vivox.com error:Access token has invalid signature(403)"
```

Which is coming from your `os.popen` command, then we filter out blank lines and attempt to `shlex.split` the line so that whitespace in quoted items is preserved (but the quotes themselves are removed), eg:

```
import os
import shlex
import pandas as pd

rows = [shlex.split(line) for line in os.popen("my command linecode").read().splitlines() if line.strip()]
```

This'll give you, for example `rows[0]` of:

```
['time:11:22:20.000',
 'instance:(null)',
 'id:723927731576482920',
 'channel:sip:confctl.com',
 'type:control',
 'elapsedtime:0.000631',
 'level:info',
 'operation:Init',
 'message:Initialize (version 4.9.0002.30618) ... ']
```

You then partition those on `:` to separate the identifier from the value and feed that into a `pd.DataFrame`, eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col.partition(':')[::2] for col in row) for row in rows)
```

Giving you a `df` of:

```
            channel elapsedtime                  id               instance  level                                            message operation          time     type
0   sip:confctl.com    0.000631  723927731576482920                 (null)   info           Initialize (version 4.9.0002.30618) ...       Init  11:22:20.000  control
1   sip:confctl.com    0.067122  723927731576482920  Ops-MacBook-Pro.local   info     Connecting to https://hrpd.www.vivox.com/api2/   Connect  11:22:21.000  control
2  sip:confctl-.com    2.685700  723927731576482920  Ops-MacBook-Pro.local   info      Connected to https://hrpd.www.vivox.com/api2/   Connect  11:22:23.000  control
3  sip:confctl-.com    2.814268  723927731576482920  Ops-MacBook-Pro.local   info                            Logged in .tester_food.     Login  11:22:23.000  control
4  sip:confctl-.com    2.912255  723927731576482920  Ops-MacBook-Pro.local  error  .tester_food. failed to join sip:confctl-2@hrp...      Call  11:22:23.000  control
```

Comment: this is exactly i was looking for but i have two kinds of logs the one which i gave you is havign limited lines i mean ther ei sjust one different line in that log which is causing me issue can you help me with that if i will edit that in the question.

Comment: @ak333 you can... but make sure adding that doesn't change the meaning of your question and invalidate the answers given please.

Comment: I have added that.... i am getting kind of list of lines on command prompt and i am storing that using popen.  Just that one long line which is giving me the stats causing the whole trouble as its different than all other lines.

Comment: I hope i edited as per your expectation. I don't mind getting two dataframes one for the line which i addded and rest for the other lines

Comment: @ak333 does that line actually end in `',` cos `shlex.split` won't be happy with that... you can try stripping `', ` from each line before splitting them and seeing if that works.... that might give you one big df and then you filter out on columns that you know only belong to those entry types etc...

Comment: No, that line is mid of the whole lines it doesn't end with , ...kind of stuck on this for a long. I will try that

Comment: @ak333 well, I've just added that line to the end of the file I was piping in via `os.popen('cat filename')` and it worked fine with the apostrophe and comma at the end... I take it you've tried running it and seeing what happens?

Comment: i didnt get you but thanks a lot for the help i will try to take it from here.